# How to enable NFC setting

Tags: android, nfc

I am able to read and wirte in my NFC demo app but I need to check if the NFC option in setting menu is enabled or not . If its not enable I want to direct the user to the setting menu(I know how to do this) similar to NFC TagWriter by NXP. 
    [image]

In my application I am using the following SDK version

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>
```

I am unable to check if the setting is enabled or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[TNR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1649309/tnr) gets it right, however also note that from Android version 16, there is a more specific settings action for NFC:

```
protected void startNfcSettingsActivity() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get the NFCAdapter.

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdpt = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if(nfcAdpt!=null)
{
if(nfcAdpt.isEnabled())
{
//Nfc settings are enabled
}
else
{
//Nfc Settings are not enabled
}
}
```

If you want to navigate user to Settings of NFC then use below Code

```
Intent setnfc = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);                             
startActivity(setnfc);
```

There is no NFC for API version 7. So change you manifest file as below

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Comment: thanks i was doing the ssame thing but was doin silly mistake :)

Comment: @MRX not an issue, if my answer helped thats ok

Comment: NFC Settings arnt inside the WIRELESS_SETTINGS on the Galaxy s6

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
        i = new Intent("android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: I can't compile with your Code ,so I change to "android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS" .It's Compiled.